# Here i want to make a table in Room database using inner class, but entity annotation isn't woring in DAO

Tags: java, android, database, android-studio

```
public class SubCategory implements Serializable {

  private ArrayList<Data> data;

  private String message;

  public ArrayList<Data> getData() {
    return this.data;
  }

  public void setData(ArrayList<Data> data) {
    this.data = data;
  }

  public String getMessage() {
    return this.message;
  }

  public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
  }


  @Entity(tableName = "SubCardsCategrories")
  public class Data implements Serializable {

    @PrimaryKey
    private Integer id;

    private String name;


    public String getName() {
      return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
      return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
      this.id = id;
    }

   
  }
}
```

I want to create the table according to DATA class parameters but it shows "Cannot figure out how to save this field into the database. You can consider adding a type converter for it "

And also table name is not accessing in my Dao interface.